# How to stop scroll event from propagating with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Lets take this simple example:

HTML:

```
<div id="A">
    <div id="B">
    </div>
</div>
```

When user moves mouse to the element B and starts to scroll, the element A should not get scroll event. How to disable scroll event from propagation?

EDIT:
I've tried this js code and it does not work. Any ideas?

```
document.getElementById("B").scroll = function(e) {e.stopPropagation();}
```

Comment: Have you tried event.stopPropagation() ? : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use event.stopPropagation(); more [info](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) 
jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pcwja3r7/1/)

Html :

```
<div id="A">
   <div id="B">

   </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$( "#A" ).scroll(function( event ) {
  alert('A scrolled');
});
$( "#B" ).scroll(function( event ) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   alert('B scrolled');
});
```

Comment: I would like to stop "scroll" event from propagation, not click event.

Answer (score 3):

The event.stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation