# disable page scroll when menu open but do not hide scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im after a solution to disable page scrolling when the menu is open, but i do not want to hide the scrollbar as the page jumps in width. I have seen a few suggestions as to how to disable scrolling but so far nothing i have tried has worked in the way i require, with the scrollbar still in view etc. had a frustrating few hours trying to solve this with no luck so far, so any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.btn-open-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').addClass('open');
     $('html').addClass('open');
    });

    $('.link-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
      $('html').removeClass('open');
      
    });

    $('.btn-close-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
     $('html').removeClass('open');
      
    });
  
      $('.btn-open-menu2').click(function () {
        $('header').addClass('open');
     $('html').addClass('open');
    });

    $('.link-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
      $('html').removeClass('open');
      
    });

    $('.btn-close-menu2').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
     $('html').removeClass('open');
      
    });
});
```

```css
/*html.open {     overflow: hidden; }*/

 header {
     width: 100%;
     
     background-color: transparent;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 10;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


 header .btn-open-menu {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     right: 50px;
     cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header .btn-open-menu {
     top: 25px;
     right: 20px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     header .header-content {
     width: 100% !important;
     }
}
 header .header-content {
     width: 30%;
     height: 100vh;
      height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
     background-color: #FB4D98;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
         left:initial; right: -100%;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-content: center;
     transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     header .header-content .btn-close-menu {
     top: 20px !important;
     right: 20px !important;
     }
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     right: 50px;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-content: center;
}
 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:before, header .header-content .btn-close-menu:after {
     background: #F4FB82;
     content: '';
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 4px;
     position: absolute;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:before {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:hover{
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
     
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:after {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

 header .header-content nav {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-content: center;
}
 header .header-content nav a {
     color: #000;
     letter-spacing: 0.5px;
     line-height: 35px;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header .header-content nav a:hover {
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     transition: 1s;
}
 header .header-content .social {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     margin: 40px 0 0 0;
     font-size: 20px;
}
 header .header-content .social a {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     margin: 0 10px;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header .header-content .social a:hover {
     color: #F4FB82;
     transform: scale(1.5);
     transition: 0.5s;
}


 header.open {
     height: 100vh;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
 header.open .btn-open-menu, header.open .logo {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
 header.open .header-content {
     left:initial; right: 0;
     transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

 .Menu-list {
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 4vw;
     line-height: 1.2;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-align: center;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .Menu-list {
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 12vw;
     }
}
 .Menu-list-item {
     position: relative;
     color: transparent;
     cursor: pointer;
}

 ul.Menu-list{
     padding-inline-start: 0px !important;
     
 }
 .Menu-list-item::before {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 49%;
     left: -10%;
     right: -10%;
     height: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     margin-top: -2px;
     background: #F4FB82;
     transform: scale(0);

     z-index: 1;
}
  .Mask {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: #F4FB82;
     top: 0;
     height: 49%;
     transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1.08, 0.38, 0.98);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .Mask {
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1.08, 0.38, 0.98);
     }
}
 .Mask span {
     display: block;
}
 .Mask + .Mask {
     top: 48.9%;
     height: 51.1%;
}
 .Mask + .Mask span {
     transform: translateY(-49%);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover .Mask, .Menu-list-item:active .Mask {
     color: #000;
     transform: skewX(12deg) translateX(5px);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover .Mask + .Mask, .Menu-list-item:active .Mask + .Mask {
     transform: skewX(12deg) translateX(-5px);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover::before, .Menu-list-item:active::before {
     transform: scale(1);
}

 
 
 .copyright {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 20px;
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 14px;
     color: black;
     white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <a class="btn-open-menu">
    <span class="hamburguer"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/hamburger.png"</span>
  </a>
  
  <div class="header-content">
    <a class="btn-close-menu"></a>

    <nav>
     <div class="Menu">
  <ul class="Menu-list" data-offset="10">
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="20" onclick="location.href='/home';">
      Home
      <span class="Mask"><span>Home</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>Home</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="16" onclick="location.href='/about';">
      About
      <span class="Mask"><span>About</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>About</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="12" onclick="location.href='/contact';">
      Contact
      <span class="Mask"><span>Contact</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>Contact</span></span>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
       </nav>
    
    <div class="social">
      
      
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/superglowcreative" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>
      </div>


      
      <div class="copyright"><span>©2020 SUPERGLOW</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Have you tried stopping the [scroll event from passing through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155681/how-to-stop-scroll-event-from-propagating-with-javascript) your overlay using JS?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `stopPropagation` event listener.

```
$( ".open" ).scroll(function( event ) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

If possible then try to add and remove `open` class to body not html

Comment: thanks, what am i adding open to body on though? been at this for hours so my brains a bit of a mess.

Comment: i dont have the scroll disabled setup at all yet, the menu just opens and closes atm and you can scroll with it in both states.

Comment: instade of $('html') use $('body') in your script. Is there any class toggle when you open and close menu?

Comment: what would changing 'html' to 'body' do?

Comment: i just tried adding your code above and changing all of the 'html' lines to 'body', but i can still scroll

Comment: Have you checked if body tag toggling "open" class on menu open and close?